# silverlight trackball

Tags: silverlight, toolkit, trackball

For days now, I've been looking for a way to show the values of a silverlight toolkit line series on a static location. I found a lot of examples using Telerik, however I don't have that software package :|

An excellent example of what I am looking for, is this:
http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=DELL

When you move the mouse over the graphic, it shows the circles on the intersection and its value on a static location. Also known in Telerik as "trackball". Just like on the yahoo site, I have 2 charts (below each other) of which I want to show the lineseries value on a static location. Does anyone know where how I can accomplish that, e.g. via an example or a hint for what XAML code to use, that does not use telerik, visibox, or any other expensive package?

Thank you!